# Disable "note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace" message

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, panic

How to disable 'note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace' when panic in Rust? My code:

```
use std::{env, fs, path::Path};
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 3{
        panic!("Incorrect args!");
    }
    let query: &String = &args[1];
    let path: &Path = Path::new(&args[2]);
    println!("Search: \"{query}\"\nPath: \"{}\"", path.to_str().unwrap());
    match path.exists(){
        true => (),
        false => {panic!("Invalid file path!");}
    }
    println!("Success");
}
```

Comment: Just, don't panic?

Comment: You can wrap your main code in [catch_unwind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) and write the panic message using your own style, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Panicking is not meant as a mechanism to handle "expected" errors. It's rather meant to indicate programming errors. For "expected" errors like non-existing files, you should use other error handling mechanisms, e.g. the anyhow crate. See also https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I largely agree with the comments/answers saying "don't", I do think there are situations where it would make sense to customize the output of a panic!

For example, if you're making a user-facing CLI, you'd maybe want to add some extra info telling the user where to report the crash.

When a thread panics, Rust calls a piece of code called the 'panic hook', which, by default, prints the `run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1` text (plus the actual backtrace, if you have that variable set).

You can override this default hook with a function/closure of your own via [`std::panic::set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html):

```rust
std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {
    println!("My cool panic output");
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use `panic!` for things it's not designed for, it is for states that can't happen unless you have a bug in your program, if you want to signal an expected error condition, you can use a `Result` in `main` like [you're supposed to anyways](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html):

```rust
use std::{env, fs, path::Path};
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 3 {
        return Err("Incorrect args!");
    }
    let query: &String = &args[1];
    let path: &Path = Path::new(&args[2]);
    println!("Search: \"{query}\"\nPath: \"{}\"", path.display());
    if !path.exists() {
        return Err("Invalid file path!");
    }
    println!("Success");
    Ok(())
}
```